# Gem Installed but bundler doesn't get it

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, bundler

I installed mocha using gem install mocha and it did install successfully. There are no version requirements of a specific version in my GEMFILE.

I still get the error :

```
Could not find mocha-0.10.3 in any of the sources
```

Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install gems from `rubygems.org`, you need to set the `source :rubygems` in the Gemfile, to make it look something like

```
source :rubygems
gem "mocha"
```

the problem might also be that your Gemfile.lock requires an older version due to some dependencies, than the one you've installed via `gem install mocha`, assuming that's what you did.

Showing contents of your Gemfile might help solve this easier though.

Comment: I managed to fix it. Thanks. I forgot some line in the Gemfile.lock :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that version of mocha [was yanked](http://rubygems.org/gems/mocha/versions/0.10.3) from RubyGems, so you will need a newer version.  If you're not hardlocked to a specific version in your Gemfile, then try a `bundle update mocha` to update your Gemfile.lock.  Otherwise, make sure you're using the spermy operator to specify the version in your Gemfile:

```
gem "mocha", "~> 0.10.5"
```